# Trouble with if circulating

Tags: c#, if-statement

My problem is that my program here have trouble circulating between the functions of button21 depending on in which order the if statements is written the if does function work but the other wont. 
in the following code i have set it to be button2 which works however i want both the buttons 1 and two to work with button21 if theyre chosen. however the function setting qw==1 is the one working in this program not qw==2
so what is the problem with my program code?
the code is displayed:

```c#
namespace Matematisk_indlæring
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Random RND = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
        Random RND2 = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
        private void quitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Hide(); 
            button2.Hide();
            button3.Hide();
            button4.Hide();
            button5.Hide();
            label1.Show();
            textBox1.Show();
            button21.Show();
            double qw = 1;
            textBox2.Text = qw.ToString();
            string q = "1+1";
            label1.Text = q;
            int qq = 1 + 1;
            textBox3.Text = qq.ToString();
        }


        private void button21_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double qqq = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            double qq = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
            int qw = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            if (qw == 1)
            {
                if (qq == qqq)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("succes");
                    int qws1;

                    int qws;

                    qws1 = RND2.Next(51, 100);


                    qws = RND.Next(0, 50);

                    qq = qws1 + qws;
                    textBox3.Text = qq.ToString();
                    string tese = qws.ToString();
                    string tese2 = qws1.ToString();
                    label1.Text = tese2 + "+" + tese;

                }

                    if (qw == 2)
                    {
                        if (qq == qqq)
                        {

                            MessageBox.Show("succes");
                            int qws1;

                            int qws;

                            qws1 = RND2.Next(51, 100);


                            qws = RND.Next(0, 50);

                            qq = qws1 - qws;
                            textBox3.Text = qq.ToString();
                            string tese = qws.ToString();
                            string tese2 = qws1.ToString();
                            label1.Text = tese2 + "-" + tese;

                        }




                }
            }
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Hide();
            button2.Hide();
            button3.Hide();
            button4.Hide();
            button5.Hide();
            label1.Show();
            textBox1.Show();
            button21.Show();
            double qw = 2;
            textBox2.Text = qw.ToString();
              string q = "1-1";
                label1.Text = q;
                int qq = 1 - 1;
                textBox3.Text = qq.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverlfow, please read [FAQ] and [ask] a couple of times..

Comment: Cool: someone putting C#'s Unicode support to use.

Comment: @nneonneo: Not cool: SO's syntax highlighting chokes on it :-(

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: SO's problem. Sounds like a good candidate for a meta question, if it hasn't already been asked.

Comment: What are you entering in `textBox1` when you say that the code does not work?

Comment: @TRMI When editing, kindly do not change the order of functions for no apparent reason. It is either too minor or too radical a change, in either case it is not a valid reason to edit.

Comment: @nneonneo      the textbox1 is the answerbox what ever the user answers will go in that textbox and then be compaired to the programs own result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least one logical flaw here.

In `button21_Click` : First you test if `qw` is 1, then right afterwards you test if it is 2. But none of the code changes `qw`. So how can it suddenly go from being 1 to becoming 2 ?

The code in this method is essentially:

```
int qw = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

if (qw == 1)
{
    if (qq == qqq)
    {
        // code which does not modify qw
    }

    if (qw == 2)          // wrong placement of this if-statement!
    {
        // code which can never be called!
    }
}
```

So as you can see, control can never reach `if (qw == 2)` in this method because you have nested the ifs wrong .. You can see this more easily if you fix the indentation.

Also: Du burde bruke engelsk klassenavn, ikke dansk :-)

Comment: thats the function of button 1 and 2 they both change the possible outcome of the double qw as you possibly be able to see they write the number to a textbox then button21 grabs that number off of the textbox

Comment: please explain to me which part of the nesting i does wrong because i really cant see the problem in my setup since the number from the textbox is grabbed before everything else??

Comment: Ok, I didn't have much going on at work right now so I updated my answer above. Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: it made it clear and i thanks you ALOT however i found that just stuffing it all in a switch statement solved my problem more easily :)

Comment: Great, glad to hear it :-)